# wso2 esb Class Mediator

Tags: wso2, esb, mediator, wso2-esb

hello I have the following class mediator created through Carbon Studio:

```
 package my.mediation;

    import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext; 
    import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

    public class Auth extends AbstractMediator { 


        public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
            // TODO Implement your mediation logic here 

            context.setProperty("message","hello world!" );

            return true;
        }

}
```

And the sequence is like:

```
<inSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <property name="message" value="nothing" scope="default" />
   <class name="my.mediation.Auth" />
   <log>
      <property name="Message******" expression="get-property('message')" />
   </log>
</inSequence
```

>
The problem is that instead of printing Message: "HelloWorld" it always print the text "nothing"...Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scenario is perfectly valid one and your configuration also seems to be fine.

I have tied your scenario and it works fine for me.

Following are my configurations.

Class Mediator:

```
package org.wso2.mediator;

import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext; 
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

public class SampleMediator extends AbstractMediator { 

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
        context.setProperty("Message", "HelloWorld!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

My proxy service:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="SimpleProxy"
    statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="http,https">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log category="INFO" level="simple" separator=","/>
            <property action="set" name="Message" scope="default"
                type="STRING" value="DefaultMessage"/>
            <class name="org.wso2.mediator.SampleMediator"/>
            <log category="INFO" level="simple" separator=",">
                <property expression="get-property('Message')" name="===========Message Value=========="/>
            </log>
            <drop/>
        </inSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

When I invoke the proxy service without the class mediator, it prints

```
INFO - LogMediator To: /services/SimpleProxy.SimpleProxyHttpSoap12Endpoint,WSAction: urn:mediate,SOAPAction: urn:mediate,MessageID: urn:uuid:81150094-cbc4-44f7-83eb-251e28149564,Direction: request,===========Message Value========== = DefaultMessage
```

and when I invoke the proxy service with the class mediator it prints,

```
INFO - LogMediator To: /services/SimpleProxy.SimpleProxyHttpSoap12Endpoint,WSAction: urn:mediate,SOAPAction: urn:mediate,MessageID: urn:uuid:e3a04341-907c-40fe-9f58-5a10d2ce346a,Direction: request,===========Message Value========== = HelloWorld!
```

Hope this helps!

Harshana

Answer (score 1):

The problem is based in the **log4j.properties**. Your class is in the package my.mediation; which does not exist in the log4j.properties. You need to go to the **YOUR_WSO2/lib/log4j.properties** and add the level of the log for your namespace/package:

```
...
log4j.logger.org.wso2=INFO
log4j.logger.my.mediation=DEBUG
```

Here you see also why the example from Harashana worked - he just changed the package to org.wso2 - which you should not do for your own custom mediators.

Comment: I don't agree with you :-). The package we use for mediator does not matters here because we do not log this message from the mediator itself. Task of the mediator is to set a value to a property which has nothing to do with logging. Hence, No. It is not the issue here. If you replace my configurations with nuvio's package name, my configuration will still work without an error. So my suggestion is to use my configuration and compare yours with mine and see what are the differences.

Comment: The package could have had an impact if we tried to log the message from the class mediator itself.

Comment: You're right. Haven't looked at the code correctly, thought the output would be done inside of the Custom Mediator. Thanks for the comment. I leave my answer anyway, maybe someone will look exactly at the problem for logs from within the Mediator.